# Using new \stdClass to get all values from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
public static function getUpdates() {

        $stmt = self::db()->run('SELECT * FROM b_updates ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1');
        $settings = new \StdClass;

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

            while($load = $stmt->fetch()) {

                $settings->{$load->title} = $load->brief;

              }
           return $settings;
        }
    }
```

I have this Code above am using that on a small scale framework. but I want to get more rows. Example as you can see I can only get Title and Brief.. I want to be able to access more rows using the code but it seems hard to me.

This is what am looking for but it has error

```
public static function getUpdates() {

        $stmt = self::db()->run('SELECT * FROM b_updates ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1');
        $settings = new \StdClass;

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {

            while($load = $stmt->fetch()) {

                $settings->$load->title;
                $setting->$load->brief;
                $settings->$load->comments;
                $settings->$load->status;


              }
           return $settings;
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate being helped or if any other solution would be given to me better :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `fetchAll()` method and you can specify the fetch_style to choose what kind of type should be fetched.

more info in the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php